# Flask Relacion one to many en sqlalchemy y flask_restfull

Tags: python, flask, restful, sqlalchemy

tengo dos modelos, uno es user y el otro userType. La relación es one to many, ej: El tipo administrador puede tener varios usuarios, un usuario solo puede ser un tipo.

Quiero poder acceder a la lista de usuarios y me devuelvan el tipo de usuario pero también, acceder a un tipo de usuario y me devuelva los usuarios de ese tipo.
Según la documentación de SQLAlchemy se tiene que utilizar "back_populates" cuando quieres que la relación sea bidireccional pero me devuelve un error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Estos son mis modelos:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin, BaseModelMixin):
  __tablename__ = 'users'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
  username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
  email = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
  password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
  create_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False, default = datetime.datetime.utcnow)
  user_type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user_types.id'), nullable=False)
  user_type = relationship("UserType", back_populates="user_type", lazy=False)


  def __init__ (self, name, username, email, user_type = {}):
      self.name = name
      self.username = username
      self.email = email
      self.user_type = user_type

class UserType(db.Model, BaseModelMixin):
  __tablename__ = 'user_types'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
  create_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False, default = datetime.datetime.utcnow)
  users = relationship("User", back_populates="user_type")

  def __init__ ( self, name, create_at,users=[]):
      self.name = name
      self.create_at = create_at
      self.users = users
```

El resultado esperado:

Si consulto a usertypes con id 1

```
{
"id": 1,
"users": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "create_time": "2021-09-13T00:00:00+03:00",
        "email": "test@test.es",
        "password": "password01",
        "name": "Admin",
        "username": "admin01"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "create_time": "2021-09-13T00:00:00+03:00",
        "email": "test2@test.es",
        "password": "password02.",
        "name": "Admin 2",
        "username": "admin2"
    }
],
"create_at": "2021-09-13T00:00:00+03:00",
"name": "Administrator"
```

}
Si consulto toda la lista de usuarios

```
     [
{
            "user_type": {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Owner",
                "create_at": "2021-09-13T00:00:00+03:00"
            },
            "password": "password03",
            "email": "test3@test.es",
            "username": "user01",
            "id": 3,
            "name": "User",
            "create_time": "2021-09-13T00:00:00+03:00"
        },
        {
            "user_type": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Administrator",
                "create_at": "2021-09-13T00:00:00+03:00"
            },
            "password": "password02.",
            "email": "test2@test.es",
            "username": "admin2",
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Admin2",
            "create_time": "2021-09-13T00:00:00+03:00"
        },
        {
            "user_type": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Administrator",
                "create_at": "2021-09-13T00:00:00+03:00"
            },
            "password": "password01",
            "email": "test@test.es",
            "username": "admin01",
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Admin",
            "create_time": "2021-09-13T00:00:00+03:00"
        }
    
    
    ]
```

Así se consultan los datos

```
import datetime
from flask import request, abort
from flask_restful import Resource


from ..schemas import UserSchema
from app.models import User

user_schema = UserSchema()



class UserListResource(Resource):
   #Obtiene todos los usuarios
   def get(self):
       users = User.get_all()
       resp = user_schema.dump(users, many = True)
       return resp


class UserResource(Resource):

   def abort_if_doesnt_exist(self, id):
       user = User.get_by_id(id)
       if user is None:
           abort(404)
       else: 
           return user

   def get(self, user_id):
    
       user = self.abort_if_doesnt_exist(user_id)
       resp = user_schema.dump(user)
       return resp
```

Y este es el esquema:

```
from marshmallow import fields
from app.ext import ma

class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
  id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
  name = fields.String(allow_none=True)
  username = fields.String(allow_none=True)
  email = fields.String(allow_none=True)
  password = fields.String(allow_none=True)
  create_time = fields.DateTime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', allow_none=True)
  user_type = fields.Nested('UserTypeSchema', many=False)
  user_type_id = fields.Integer(default = 3)
```

Comment: Saludos estimado, el error RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded, no se debe a la forma de tus modelos, puede deberse a la forma en como consultas tus datos, podrias publicar el codigo donde haces la busqueda de los tipos de usuarios a traves del usuario y viceversa?

Comment: Buenas @VictorAlvarado, ya lo he actualizado, dime si necesitas algo mas. Y gracias.